# How to batch align hundreds of images (50x50px) into a single image (A3) given items per row?

Tags: image, printing, alignment, batch-processing

I need to align hundreds or even thousands of tiny images (QR codes) into a single image which will then be printed on an A3 paper.

I created a small application which loops through all the images contained into a folder and gets each image (sorted by name) and joins it to the main image.
I can give as input the amount of items per row and it will correctly go to a new line when needed (also allowing to set an offset).

The problem is that it takes ages and even giving 8GB to the VM, it wasn't enough... (It reached 6GB before crashing)

Since I just need to do this once, is there a software or something which does it nicely for me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good solution: http://kalanir.blogspot.se/2010/02/how-to-merge-multiple-images-into-one.html